# Number becomes to BigDecimal after the hibernate reverse engeering?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, numbers, bigdecimal

I set the field as **Number** like below in the **oracle database**.

> name             type    length      scale
>   EMP_GENDER  NUMBER    0               0

After the hibernate reverse engineering,this filed's type becomes to **BigDecimal**.

```
private BigDecimal empGender;
```

But when I set the length to **2** in database,it could be right and field type in the entity become to **Integer**.
How did this happen?

Comment: How exactly the `EMP_GENDER` column is defined. Zero precision and zero scale cannot be specified for `number` data type or any other numeric data type in Oracle.

Comment: why would you have Gender as a number?

Comment: @user2310289 Is there something more suitable ?

Comment: gender char(1) check (gender in ( 'M', 'F' )),

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I don't know how to let you know it is workable.But I really just did it in my **Navicat for Oracle 11.0.9**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Hibernate reverse engineers your schema, that will use Oracle's Mete-data tables to extract table and columns information.
One of the them will be `user_tab_columns` View.

Having

```
create table EMP (EMP_GENDER number);
```

To extract EMP table,s column information you may use:

```
select *
from user_tab_columns
where user_tab_columns.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
```

The query result will be characterization of every column of `EMP` table.
We will see `DATA_TYPE` , `DATA_LENGTH` and `DATA_PRECISION` columns.
(using Oracle 10 g)
[image]

Having:

```
create table EMP (EMP_GENDER number(2));
```

We will see
[image]

When not defining precision for numeric type, the DATA_LENGTH (default is `22` ) will be treated as precision.
So a number with length of 22 will be translated to Big-decimal by Hibernate(that will exceed the maximum precision of `decimal` data type) 
When numeric type precision is equals to 2, the `Integer` data type will be sufficient.

You must specify the exact numeric precision on table creation to prevent the problem.